# Will BigQuery charge me for export data from Firebase Analytic

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm quite new to the service Bigquery.

My situation is I'm linking the Firebase Analytic to Bigquery to make some of analytic stuff (Blaze Plan upgraded).

I found that every day, the BigQuery automatically generates an event table with data from Firebase. My question is: will I be charged for that operation ? I'm afraid of charging for streaming insert, you know.

fyi: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples

Thanks for viewing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firebase and BigQuery without a credit card, within the monthly free tier limits.

However streaming into BigQuery is not free, and (for now) Analytics for Firebase exports data into BigQuery through streaming, so there will be an associated cost.

Meanwhile there is Firebase data that you can get for free into BigQuery:

- Crashlytics
- Cloud Messaging
- Predictions

https://firebase.google.com/docs/bigquery-export#pricing